# django template radio button submit

Tags: django

I have a django template which contains a table and some records. on radio button click i want to get that particular records values in views.py via get request.
    the for loop does not work fine..pls suggest

```
{% for request in requests %}
<tr>
<td>
<tr>
<td><input type ="text" value ={{ request.workflowId}} readonly name ="workflid" STYLE="background-color: pink;"  /></td>
    <td><input type ="text" value ={{ request.proj_name}} readonly name ="projname" STYLE="background-color: pink;"  /></td>
    <td><input type ="text" value ={{ request.task }} readonly name ="id1" STYLE="background-color: pink;"  /></td>
    <td><input type ="text" value ={{ request.date }}readonly name ="id1" STYLE="background-color: pink;"  /></td>
    <td><input type ="text" value ={{ request.enteredby }} readonly name ="id1" STYLE="background-color: pink;"  /></td>
    <td> <input type = "text" align ="center" readonly name = "status" value = {{ request.status }} STYLE="background-color: pink;"  /></td>
    <td><input type = "text" value ={{ request.assignto }} readonly name = "asgnto" STYLE="background-color: pink;" /></td>
    <td><input type = "radio" name ="radio1" onclick ="validate_values()"</td>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Add more information about your question.

Comment: can you add the code of `validate_values`? Also, what problem are you having with the for loop? The code of the view that renders the template could help, too.

Comment: validate_values doesnt have any code.

Comment: actually when I am selecting the radio button. I expect that workflow to be selected and should be passed on submit but actually i get the last value of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Into your form having `method="GET"` just put `action="/yoururl/{{request.workflowId}}/"`
so using value of id into url you can differentiate particular field values into your view.